# How to use takeown and icacls to deny access to other users?

Tags: windows, command-line, permissions, icacls

What is the Windows equivalent to:

```
chown $USER
chmod 600 file
```

From what I understand, this requires that inherited permissions be disabled (because HOSTNAME\Users is inherited) and all groups outside of myself and Administrators be removed.

Can this operation be performed with `takeown` and `icacls`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take ownership, so that the previous owner (if any) couldn't change permissions. Use takeown command to do this :

```
takeown /f filepath
```

Disable automatic inheritance:

```
icacls filepath /inheritance:d
```

Grant yourself full control:

```
icacls filepath /grant user:f
```

Finally remove everyone else:

```
icacls filepath /remove someotheruser
```

Anyone who is not listed in the ACL will be denied by default.